# Events not being passed to Bootstrap tabs when in ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers 3 to make a map interface. Selecting a vector feature brings up a small control panel (extending `ol.control.Control`). I'm trying to add multiple tabs to this control panel using Twitter Bootstrap, but I'm finding that the events which are needed to trigger the tab switch aren't making it to Bootstrap. I've traced down that this is because controls are placed into a `<div>` with CSS class `ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent`, which is somehow preventing the listener in Bootstrap from hearing the event.

Here's a [stripped down JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2kk1cbyj/6/) of what I'm trying to do. You can see that clicking the tabs doesn't do anything. Any idea how to make sure this event gets to the Bootstrap tab listener?

P.S. From the Bootstrap source code, it appears that the listeners are defined by

```
$(document)
    .on('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"]', clickHandler)
    .on('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="pill"]', clickHandler)
```

Comment: Which moment you define a click listener in your fiddle?

Comment: @jonatas-walker See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L2196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add a `click` event to your page so, add it:

```
$('#prop-box-content li > a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target);
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Yep. I figured this out yesterday but forgot to come back to this question. It's still frustrating that the listener registered by Bootstrap.js gets neutered by OpenLayers.

Comment: I actually elected to use a form more like that used in Bootstrap.js itself:

    `$('[data-toggle="tab"],[data-toggle="pill"]', box).click(function (e) { 
          e.preventDefault() 
          $(this).tab('show') 
        });`